# cordova - Splashscreen and app screen not working on Phonegap Build cli-6.1.0

Tags: ios, cordova, screen, fullscreen, splash-screen

We were using Phonegap 3.7.0 till now and everything was working perfectly fine. Now we have requirement to upgrade to Phonegap 6.1.0 and with this we are facing problems with splash screen on iOS and the application screen is also not working properly. Below is the how we see login screen:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fpar.png)
We are using cordova cordova-plugin-splashscreen and in config.xml we have added statements as mentioned in documentation on that plugin, but somehow splash screen is not visible.

Below is the code we have added in config.xml:

```
<platform>
<gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default~iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" height="768"/>
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" height="1536"/>
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242"/>
</platform>

<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="4000" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding ios for platform name:

```
<platform name="ios">
   <splash src="splash/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
   ...
</platform>
```